# I can't upgrade Linux Mint — unmet dependencies

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, dependencies

I installed Linux Mint 19 “Tara” Cinnamon, and when I want to upgrade or sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, there is some bug:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-sensors:i386 : Depends: libappindicator3-1:i386 (>= 0.2.96) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libatasmart4:i386 (>= 0.13) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1:i386 (>= 0.9.2) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.28.0) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libgtk-3-0:i386 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libnotify4:i386 (>= 0.7.2) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libpeas-1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libsensors4:i386 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installed
                          Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not installed
                          Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend:i386 but it is not installed or
                                   gsettings-backend:i386
                          Depends: gir1.2-peas-1.0:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: did you tried the mention fix ? `apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Also I thnik `apt-get update apt-get upgrade` is better than `apt-get update apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: -1 for having an instruction there in plain English that was not followed.

Comment: @Kiwy it does different things: `upgrade` only upgrades to the latest package versions, `dist-upgrade` also upgrades the kernel version.

Comment: @Fiximan I think your misunderstanding the function of `dist-upgrade` and `upgrade` both upgrade the kernel. It's the method they use to resolve dependencies. `dist-upgrade` is a bit more aggressive in its dependencies resolution.

Answer (score 2):

The program [`indicator-sensors`](https://github.com/alexmurray/indicator-sensors)  is developed and packaged as a [`snap`](https://snapcraft.io/indicator-sensors).

1) remove the `indicator-sensors` and its ppa :

```
sudo apt remove indicator-sensors
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors
```

2) Run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

3) Upgrade :`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

4) Install the `indicator-sensors` package:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install indicator-sensors
```

Starting from Ubuntu 16.04 the package `indicator-sensors` can't be installed properly. It may cause some issues.

The bug:  [Missing package for ubuntu xenial](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sensors/+bug/1633123)

The answer of the maintainer:

> [Alex Murray (alexmurray) wrote on 2018-06-18:#3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sensors/+bug/1633123/comments/3)
>
> You can now install via snap - https://snapcraft.io/indicator-sensors
>
> snap install indicator-sensors